# Check if a variable is between two values with Python

Tags: python

I am calculating a person's BMI in Python 3 and need to check if the BMI is between two values.

This is my code:

```
def metricBMI():

    text = str('placeholder')

    #Get height and weight values 
    height = float(input('Please enter your height in meters: '))
    weight = float(input('Please enter your weight in kilograms: '))

    #Square the height value
    heightSquared = (height * height)

    #Calculate BMI
    bmi = weight / heightSquared

    #Print BMI value
    print ('Your BMI value is ' + str(bmi))

    if bmi < 18:
        text = 'Underweight'

    elif 24 >= bmi and bmi >= 18:
        text = 'Ideal'

    elif 29 >= bmi and bmi >= 25:
        text = 'Overweight'

    elif 39 >= bmi and bmi >= 30:
        text = 'Obese'

    elif bmi > 40:
        text = 'Extremely Obese'

    print ('This is: ' + text)
```

This will output Underweight perfectly fine but others like Ideal do not define text.

Output:

```
Calulate BMI, BMR or Harris Benedict Equation (HBE) or exit? bmi
Do you work in metric (M) or imperial (I)m
Please enter your height in meters: 1.8
Please enter your weight in kilograms: 80
Your BMI value is 24.691358024691358
This is: placeholder
```

I'm guessing there is something wrong with the way I'm checking the variable but I can't see it.

Thanks,

Jake

Comment: Please fix the code indent.

Comment: you should go with answer by [Ashalynd](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33035965/2723675) for your use case, but in case someone stumbles upon this page based on the title, you can check if a variable is between two numbers like this: `if min < num < max:`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your BMI does not fall under any of your conditions (it's more than 24 and less than 25, and this is not covered by your cases).

In fact, you can simplify your conditioning like this:

```
if bmi < 18:
    text = 'Underweight'

elif bmi <= 24: # we already know that bmi is >=18 
    text = 'Ideal'

elif bmi <= 29:
    text = 'Overweight'

elif bmi <= 39:
    text = 'Obese'

else:
    text = 'Extremely Obese'
```

Comment: sorry cancel... elifs will be skipped after true...  would be better to have explicit ranges though.   will delete my comment

Answer (score 0):

You may need to convert the bmi to an integer value.

```
bmi = int (weight / heightSquared)
```

Also you may need Extremely Obse to be >= 39 (not 40).

Answer (score 0):

I can't run python to test it but by simply inspecting your code I can tell you have a bug in your logic.

Your Ideal BMI ends at 24 (inclusive) and Overweight starts at 25 (inclusive).So your if's are not covering values between 24 and 25 at all. So your example of BMI 24.7 is not covered by either.

You can fix this simply by making Overweight starting at 24 (exclusive). You have the exact same logic fault between Overweight and Obese.